# Не отображается кнопка Android

Tags: android, button

Здравствуйте.
Не отображается кнопка "Купить" (@+id/btnPay в конце кода). В ходе проведенных тестов замечено, что не отображается она на экранах >=4 и <5 дюймов. На остальных экранах кнопка есть. Если закинуть эту кнопку в другой уже существующий лайоут - кнопка отображается и реагирует на нажатия.
В чем может быть проблема?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutSale"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="0dp" >

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutSaleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layout_marginBottomAll"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_marginLeftAll"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/layout_marginRightAll"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_marginTopAll"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/paddingBottomAll"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/paddingLeftAll"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/paddingRightAll"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/paddingTopAll" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textSale"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeTextSale" >
            </TextView>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_line"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp" >
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/paddingLeftTvDateTvDayAll" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDate2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeTvDateAll" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDay2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeTvDayAll" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:onClick="onClickPay" >
        </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Может просто в экран не влезло? Что если всю разметку в `ScrollView` обернуть?

Comment: Тоже думал, что не влезло, пробовал сдвигать вверх лайоут кнопки через android:paddingBottom - 0 результат, на других экранах сдвигается и сжимает вверх лайоут  с ScrollView (как и должно быть). Закидывать кнопку в ScrollView - не хочу.

Comment: Я не предлагаю обязательно оборачивать - я предлагаю проверить предположение о том, что она просто не влезла. Если это так - можно будет переделать разметку так, чтобы влезло. Иначе - можно будет подумать в чём ещё может быть дело.

Comment: Я уже писал, что если код кнопки закинуть в верхний лайоут, то кнопка отображается. Или ты не про это?

Comment: Ну, вроде про это. Значит да, просто не влезает. Придётся вам или в `ScrollView` оборачивать, или подбирать высоту элементам. Возможно, что-то выкинуть.

Comment: Пробовал сжимать лайоут с ScrollView на пол экрана, но кнопка не появляется

Comment: Вот этот сжимали? layoutSaleText,

Comment: да, через layout_marginBottom

Comment: Эээ... А как через `layout_marginBottom` сжимать?.. Попробуйте через простановку высоты лучше

Comment: Через layout_height увидел кнопку. Осталось самое малое -подгадать под все экраны. Спасибо за терпение и помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае кнопку не видно, т.к. она просто не влезла в экран. Решить проблему можно или уменьшив высоту вышележащих элементов разметки или обернув их все в `ScrollView`